# VB.Net - Using Regular Expressions to Filter a Filename

Tags: .net, regex, replace, find, expression

I think im overcomplicating something simple but im looking for a VB.Net code to "filter" file names.

Scenario:
My company has a folder on the server with over 65,000 files on it. The new machine that reads those files is case sensitive and only accepts "*.S4" file extensions.

So, I need to convert all the file names to "*.S4" but I'd like the option to replace each file with a pattern I Specify.

### For example:

Find > test.s4

Replace > test_1.S4

### Using Patterns:

Find > *.s4

Replace > *_1.S4

### Heres the code I have so far (doesnt work):

```
    'Inputs:
    Dim Filename As String = "ThisIsAnExample.s4"
    Dim Find As String = "*.s4"
    Dim Replace As String = "*.S4"

    Find = Find.Replace("*", "(.*)")
    Replace = Replace.Replace("*", "(.*)")

    Dim rgxExp As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(Find)

    MsgBox(rgxExp.Replace(Filename, Replace))
```

I know its possible, I wrote a similar script in Javascript once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you do this?

```
  Dim input As String = "ThisIsAnExample.s4"
  Dim pattern As String = "\.s4$"
  Dim replacement As String = ".S4"
  Dim rgx As New Regex(pattern)
  Dim result As String = rgx.Replace(input, replacement)

  Console.WriteLine("Original String: {0}", input)
  Console.WriteLine("Replacement String: {0}", result)
```

Comment: I'd like to have the option for wildcard. "(.*).s4" then replace that with "renamed_(*.).S4" See what I mean? Basically reformatting the filename based on the users input, I wont be using this program myself. Other, non-computer literate people will. They understand the basics of wildcards.

Comment: @Rob LOL. OK but what you wrote there isn't a valid regex. Just provide some more samples before and after reformatting and I will find the regex you need :)

Comment: On the whole though, this could work. Im not that experienced with Regular Expressions but i presume the "\" indicates its not at the start ? and "$" represents end of line?

Comment: @Rob Actually \ is just to escape the dot and $ is the end of the line as you said.

Comment: Oh right. Because otherwise its considered to be a wildcard in Regular Expressions right... That maybe why im getting some issues. I havent escaped any special characters. =\

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to do this using c# without regex you could use the following

```
    private void UppercaseExtension(string filepath)
    {
        //ensure the source file exists
        if (!File.Exists(filepath))
            return;

        //get the parts of the filepath
        string filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filepath);
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(filepath).ToUpperInvariant();
        string folderPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(filepath);
        try
        {
            //rename the file using the uppercase extension
            File.Move(filepath, Path.Combine(folderPath, filename + extension));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //failed to rename
        }
    }
```

If you wanted to limit the types of file you could add a check to do this inside the method or you could limit the file paths being passed to it.

Comment: This doesn't look like VB to me :)

Comment: Sorry looking at the tags I only saw .net, if you need a vb example ask and I will convert it for you. Shouldn't be too different.

Comment: I don't want anything :) I am not the OP ;)

Comment: Sorry 53AN, because i had low reputation it told me i could only have 5 tags? I had to delete the rest -.-

Comment: I could easily translate this to VB.Net if i needed too anyways. No worries!